# Is it better to create a string in Java as an object or as a primitive type?

Tags: java, string

My understanding of `strings` in Java is that they can be either primitive types or objects. When creating strings is it better to create them as objects with the new command and a constructor or as a primitive type similar to int?

Comment: Strings are always objects in Java, regardless of whether or not `new` keyword is used. It usually doesn't make sense to use the `new` keyword though, since it forces the creation of a new instance instead of re-using String instances in the String pool.

Comment: String is always a object.

Comment: Even when it is declared as `String courseName = "math";`  ?

Comment: Yes, this still creates a String object that contains the value "math". This way is preferable to `new String("math")` though.

Comment: Yes.. but String literals are saved in String Constant pool but not in Heap

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera - String constants pool is at the end part of heap :P

Comment: @TheLostMind yeah I know.. but they will be in special place called PermGen space( permanent generation ).  Since it is a separate region, it is not considered part of the Java Heap space

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera - *Since JDK 7, interned strings are no longer allocated in the permanent generation of the Java heap, but are instead allocated in the main part of the Java heap (known as the young and old generations), along with the other objects created by the application.* Check [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html#jdk7changes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *My understanding of strings in Java is that they can be either primitive types or objects*

Wrong. Strings are always *objects*. Its just that *String literals* (`"someStringHere"`) are treated in a special manner by the compiler and then interned by the JVM.

If your question is whether -

`String s = "Abc";` 
is better than 
`String s = new String("Abc");`,
Yes, since the second one is redundant and creates 2 Strings (one in constants pool and another on heap).

Comment: that was a helpful and clear answer. Thank you.

Comment: @user1454994 you should mark it as correct one

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg I have to wait ten minutes until I can do so.